# How can I get Nautilus to work with X11 forwarding over SSH? I'm getting a bunch of errors related to D-Bus

Tags: macos, ssh, xorg, nautilus

Here's where things stand right now.

- I have Nautilus successfully running under Mac OS X 10.8 on a Mac Mini, installed via MacPorts.
- I am trying to pull it up on a second screen on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. Or really on any other computer.
- I have been able to successfully run simple X11 apps like xeyes via X11 forwarding, so I am confident I have forwarding set up correctly.
- When I try to run Nautilus via forwarding, [I get this long list of errors. I've put it up on pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/zLh8pePP)

I definitely have dbus installed on the Pi, though I don't really know what it is. I'm not sure what's behind these errors or if there's anything I can do about it. Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try: "Failed to get connection to session: Session D-Bus not running. Try running `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist`.)" as it suggests?  I see nothing in your post saying anything on that.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that. Yes I tried that. When run on the Mac it ran without any output. On the Pi that command did not exist, and I couldn't find it in apt-cache. I think it's a Mac specific or MacPorts specific thing.

Comment: Yes, `launchctl` is Apple's daemon initializer.